# Error While converting a String to an Int Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

So I receive a string in the form of an IP/PortNumber:WaitTime as a string. I have split these two on the ":" So i recieve two parts, the IP/Potnumber as one and the WaitTime as a string as another. Ive tried to convert this string to int but I keep getting an error that the string is not valid.

Error:

[image: This is an updated image showing the output of the second block of code. The print statmetn shows there are no blank spaces]
[image: This is how i take the input from the user.[![][3]]][3]

```
public static int GetJob (String recieved) {
    String[] arrOfJob = recieved.split(":");
    int accjob =0;
    try {
        accjob = Integer.parseInt(arrOfJob[1]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return accjob;
}


public static int GetJob (String recieved) {
    String[] arrOfJob = recieved.split(":");
    int accjob =0;
    System.out.print("/"+arrOfJob[1]+"/");
    try {
        accjob = Integer.parseInt(arrOfJob[1]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return accjob;
}
```

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: Error Posted as a picture

Comment: Your code working at my side, for input: 192.168.229.1/3900:1000. Could you check you are using any space or use `trim()`

Comment: Why am I getting this error then?

Comment: There is no problem in the code for input `"192.168.229.1/3900:1000"`

Comment: @user11432150 Put the input that you have used

Comment: Is there a stacktrace in addition to the exception message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public static int getJob(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split(":");
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(split[1].trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Yer this works! Thank you very much. Where did I go wrong though?

Comment: I think, there are spaces in your input. causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try the instanceof in java and check whether you are parsing string or double or other data types.

Example :

```
Integer i = 0;
if(i instanceof Integer) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Output :

```
true
```

Make sure the variables should be of object(Integer,Double,..) not primitive types(int,double,..).

The reason NumberFormatException will be occuring for the non parsable values.